# Multi chat - determine which user saw the message (ejabberd)

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I'm pretty new with ejabberd and I have two questions.

1. What is the best approach to check which user seen a message or to see where the user stopped reading?
2. Do you know any open source clients written in javascript except or similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pazznetwork/ngx-chat?

Thanks and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, I guess one implementation path would be that the client and server support https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html and also https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html and also that those two can work together, and that they work in MUC rooms. I don't expect that to work.

For 2, what about https://conversejs.org/ ?